# Entity Framework: a proxy collection for displaying a subset of data

Tags: entity-framework, collections

Imagine I have an entity called Product and a repository for it:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRepository
{
    public ObservableCollection<Product> AllProducts { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Product> HiddenProducts { get; set; }
}
```

All products contains every single Product in the database, while HiddenProducts must only contain those, whose `IsHidden == true`. I wrote the type as `ObservableCollection<Product>`, but it does not have to be that.

The goal is to have `HiddenProducts` collection be like a proxy to `AllProducts` with filtering capabilities and for it to refresh every time when `IsHidden` attribute of a Product is changed.

Is there a normal way to do this? Or maybe my logic is wrong and this could be done is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up on `CollectionView`/`CollectionViewSource` stuff.